# Can you pass Variable Group values to sub template in yaml?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a multi-stage pipeline which has Variable Groups defined for each stage of the pipeline. The goal is to pass values from the group as parameters to a sub template. It seems the value of the Group, defined at the stage, is not getting passed in to the sub template. It overrides the "DEFAULTVALUE" with an empty string.

**pipeline.yml**

```yaml
    trigger:
    - none

    pool:
      name: 'Azure Pipelines'
      vmImage: windows-latest

    stages:
      - stage: DEV
        variables:
          - group: my-group-dev
        jobs:
          - template: sub-template.yml
            parameters:
              env: 'dev'
              subscriptionName: '$(SubscriptionName)' # This reference from the variable group doesn't get passed in
              subscriptionId: '$(SubscriptionId)'

      - stage: TEST
        variables:
          - group: my-group-test
        jobs:
          - template: sub-template.yml
            parameters:
              env: 'test'
              subscriptionName: '$(SubscriptionName)' # This reference from the variable group doesn't get passed in
              subscriptionId: '$(SubscriptionId)'
```

**sub-template.yml**

```yaml
    parameters:
      env: 'DEFAULTVALUE'
      subscriptionName: 'DEFAULTVALUE'
      subscriptionId: 'DEFAULTVALUE'

    jobs:
      - deployment: ResourceDeployment
        displayName: Deploy Resources ${{ parameters.env }}
        environment: ${{ parameters.env }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureFileCopy@4
                  displayName: 'Upload ARM Templates'
                  inputs:
                    sourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/templates'
                    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}'
                    destination: 'azureBlob'
                    storage: 'my-storage-account'
                    containerName: 'arm'
                  name: AzureFileCopy

                - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
                  inputs:
                    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                    azureResourceManagerConnection: '${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}'
                    subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}'
                    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                    resourceGroupName: 'my-resource-group'
                    location: 'eastus2'
                    templateLocation: 'URL of the file'
                    csmFileLink: '$(AzureFileCopy.StorageContainerUri)${{ parameters.env }}/templates/main.json$(AzureFileCopy.StorageContainerSasToken)'
```

I have also tried adding the variable group within the sub-template but that also doesn't parse correctly...

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known issue that the service connection endpoint cannot be referenced in variable groups defined under stage level.

You can fix this issue by below workarounds:

1, Define the variable groups in the **global level** instead of **stage level** See below:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-latest

# define the variable group under global level.

variables:
- group: my-group-dev
- group: my-group-test


stages:
  - stage: DEV
    jobs:
      - template: sub-template.yml
        parameters:
          env: 'dev'
          subscriptionName: '$(SubscriptionName)' # This reference from the variable group doesn't get passed in
          subscriptionId: '$(SubscriptionId)'

  - stage: TEST
    jobs:
      - template: sub-template.yml
        parameters:
          env: 'test'
          subscriptionName: '$(SubscriptionName)' # This reference from the variable group doesn't get passed in
          subscriptionId: '$(SubscriptionId)'
```

2, Link the variable groups on the UI page.

On the yaml pipeline edit page--> Click the 3dots-->Triggers-->Variables Tab-->Link Variable group

[image]

[image]

Please see below threads for more information.

[Using a variable for the service connection](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676259/using-a-variable-for-the-service-connection-result.html)

[Azure subscription endpoint ID cannot be provided through a variable in build definition YAML file](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1307)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try adding shared variable groups and accessing the service connection name by convention.

Comment: Got it fixed by knowing that it's just the service connection parameters that are an issue. Thanks for your help and I hope MSFT get it sorted soon so nobody else has to endure that nonsense!

Comment: Hi Levi, I've just had a fresh look at this. I eventually got it working by using some info from the Github issue. It involves referencing a "shared" variable group that holds the connection names of both connections, and then passing as a parameter to the sub step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variable group name to template and on template level apply it on variables scope like this:

```yaml
parameters:
  env: 'DEFAULTVALUE'
  subscriptionName: 'DEFAULTVALUE'
  subscriptionId: 'DEFAULTVALUE'
  variableGroupName: 'DEFAULTVALUE`

jobs:
  - deployment: ResourceDeployment
    displayName: Deploy Resources ${{ parameters.env }}
    environment: ${{ parameters.env }}
    variables:
      - group: {{ paramaters.variableGroupName }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: AzureFileCopy@4
              displayName: 'Upload ARM Templates'
              inputs:
                sourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/templates'
                azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}'
                destination: 'azureBlob'
                storage: 'my-storage-account'
                containerName: 'arm'
              name: AzureFileCopy

            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
              inputs:
                deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                azureResourceManagerConnection: '${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}'
                subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}'
                action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                resourceGroupName: 'my-resource-group'
                location: 'eastus2'
                templateLocation: 'URL of the file'
                csmFileLink: '$(AzureFileCopy.StorageContainerUri)${{ parameters.env }}/templates/main.json$(AzureFileCopy.StorageContainerSasToken)'
```

This is similar to [this topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1266925/variables-defined-on-pipeline-level-are-not-availa.html):

> For security reasons, we only allow you to pass information into templated code via explicit parameters.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops
>
> The means the author of the pipeline using your template needs to commit changes where they explicitly pass the needed info into your template code.
>
> There are some exceptions to this, where the variable is statically defined in the same file or at pipeline compile time, but generally speaking, it’s probably better to use parameters for everything that does not involve system-defined read-only dynamic variable and custom-defined dynamic output variables.

I have to variables groups

- QA
- PROD

both has `isProd` variable

and then my template is

```yaml
parameters:
  variableGroupName: 'QA'

jobs:
- job: ResourceDeployment
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}
  steps:
  - script: echo '$(isProd)'
```

and main file is

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - template: sub-template.yml
    parameters:
      variableGroupName: 'QA'

- stage: PROD
  jobs:
  - template: sub-template.yml
    parameters:
      variableGroupName: 'PROD'
```

and I got:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will give that a try soon - Dave

Comment: Hi, that didn't cure it. I am referencing the value of azureSubscription in the AzureFileCopy task as `$(_ServiceConnectionName)`. I've tried with quotes, without quotes and also `${{ variables._ServiceConnectionName }}`.

Comment: And `_ServiceConnectionName` is a name of variable in variable group?

Comment: Also tried `$[variables._ServiceConnectionName]` as another method without joy. What on earth am I missing!?

Comment: Can you check my edit? I tested this approach on simpler case and all works.

Comment: I'll give that a try to get it working with a simple test, then will start making it more complex with the Deployment job. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Here do you use `_ServiceConnectionName`? On given example I don't see this.

Comment: On my example I was originally trying to access it as a parameter. passed from the main template

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. It seems the other guy (Levi) hit the nail on the head with the fact that it's a problem referencing a service connection name. Some strange inner workings on MSFT's part, but for now at least I have it working...

Comment: @DavidC cool. Glad you solved your issue.