# How to create CI/CD pipeline for QnAMaker ChatBot Virtual Assistant Template in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, botframework

I am using Bot Framework Virtual Assistant template to Create and configure Bot in Azure,
For this process i have ARM template is in place for creating resources,
Deploy PS script is used to create knowledgebase and (Deploy.ps1) once qnamaker resources are created.

In current implementation, If i execute script from local Powershell tool everything works fine:

1. Creating Resources
2. Creating Knowledgebase
3. KnowledgeBase configuration

I am stuck at configuring this set up in Azure DevOps, How do i configure ARM deployment and PowerShell script execution in CI/CD pipeline.
So that once resources are created through ARM deployment, Knowledgebase creation should automatically trigger ?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put the ARM template in a source repository(Github or Azure Repos).  See document [Create a new Git repo in your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops)

Then Create the pipeline(Yaml or Classic). See YAML example [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition). For Classic UI pipeline check out [this example](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/).

Before you can deploy to your Azure subscription. You need to create an [azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) to connect your Azure subscription to Azure devops. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637419/azure-devops-service-connection-is-not-being-recognized/65661278#65661278) for an example

In your pipeline use [ARM template deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) to deploy the ARM template. And use [Azure powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) to execute the Deploy PS script.  See below example

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Subscription scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'my-azure-sub'
    resourceGroupName: 'azrue resource group'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: **/template.json
    csmParametersFile: **/parameter.json
    deploymentMode: Incremental

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: FilePath'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-azure-sub'
    ScriptPath: **/Deploy.ps1
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

See [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-tutorial-pipeline) for more information.

Comment: Hello @Levi Lu-MSFT, The challenge i am facing is to get output of deploy.ps1 and use it for updating cognitive model, the script deploy.ps1 generates certain keys (kbid auth key etc) and these keys needs to be used by release pipeline where we have to update cognitive model, i even referred https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/solution-accelerators/tutorials/enable-continuous-deployment/3-configure-pipeline/  document but it is not clearly mentioned how output variables of build pipe line being used in release pipeline for updating cognitive model, hope you understood my concern