# Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-devops

When attempting to complete a pull request and deploy to Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

```
Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired.
```

I added a new token since the old one was expired and deleted the old one, but when I went to re-deploy, I still got the same error.

Then, I tried the following approach in an answer on a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65661278 :

1. Go to Project settings > Service connections, and then select the service connection you want to modify.
2. Select Edit in the upper-right corner, and then make any change to your service connection. The easiest and recommended change is to add a description.
3. Select Save to save the service connection. Don't try to verify the service connection at this step.
4. Exit the service connection edit window, and then refresh the service connections page.
5. Select Edit in the upper-right corner, and now select Verify. (You may need to select a valid Resource group first if one isn't already selected.)
6. Select Save to save your service connection.

But whenever I try to hit "Save" on step 6, I get the following error:

```
TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred: Activity Id:
```

Not sure really where to go from here. Can provide more info if needed! Thank you!

**NOTE:** I've created a both a new token and a federated credential. When I try to update the "AzureAd": "Client Id" and "TenantId" with the updated credentials and rerun the pull request, I still get the same error message. I made sure to double check the "ClientId" and "TenantId" to make sure the credentials match the secret and the federated credential and they do.
[Certificates and Secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6FeP.png)

[Federated Credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CobGr.jpg)

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt71G.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't look like a C# or programming question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you are using DevOps Pipeline to deploy your app to Azure Web App. If I misunderstood, please describe your issue in detail.

The possible reason why you encountered the error "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred" when you clicked "Save" at step 6 is that you do not have sufficient permissions. Please try to ask the user with Subscription owner role in your organization to perform the same steps to update the service connection. If there is the same issue, please share the Activity Id.

As a workaround, if you still want to use the same service principal, you can create a new ARM service connection using **Service principal (manual)**. Then use the new one to deploy your app.
[image]

Fill in the following information, click "Verify" and save the service connection.

- Service Principal Id: Application (client) ID of your SP.
- Credential: Select Service principal key
- Service principal key: The value of your secret

[image]

Comment: The full error is: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 5fef0386-da99-466e-bf0b-dd87a076c98a.As for adding a New Service Connection, I don't see "Service Principal (manual)", the only things I see that look close to the are "Azure Classic", "Azure repos/Team Foundation Server", "Azure Resource Manager", "Azure Service Plus"

Comment: According to the activity Id, your account doesn't have enough permission. As I mentioned above, please contact a user who has the 'Owner' or 'User Access Administrator' permissions on the Subscription to edit the old service connection. To create a new SC, please go to **New service connection** -> Select "**Azure Resource Manager**" -> Then select "**Service principal (manual)**".

Comment: I had the owner of the site follow these exact instructions, but after I entered the info the "verify" button remained greyed out. I think Microsoft might have deprecated this feature.

Comment: Can you help clarify what you mean by "owner of the site"? Are you the owner of Azure Subscription or the owner of Azure DevOps organization? Or something else? Regarding "the "verify" button remained grayed out", can you share a screenshot of when you tried to click the "verify" button?

Comment: Edited original post, I've now updated secret but still having issues.

Comment: @Matthew Pourroy, please check whether your pipeline has been updated to use the **new** service connection.