# Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired, resource name 'ProStrideSkating-api-dev'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Full error message: "Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired. Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'ProStrideSkating-api-dev'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Status code: invalid_client, status message: 7000222 - [2024-01-10 19:23:44Z]: AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys for app '***' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app: https://aka.ms/NewClientSecret, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: [https://aka.ms/certCreds.[error]Unhandled](https://aka.ms/certCreds.%5Berror%5DUnhandled): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getApplicationURL')"

So far, I followed the advice of both [Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701344/error-could-not-fetch-access-token-for-azure-verify-if-the-service-principal-u) and [Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired. Failed to get resource ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760936/error-could-not-fetch-access-token-for-azure-verify-if-the-service-principal-u)

I've created a both a new token and a federated credential. When I try to update the "AzureAd": "Client Id" and "TenantId" with the updated credentials and rerun the pull request, I still get the same error message. I made sure to double check the "ClientId" and "TenantId" to make sure the credentials match the secret and the federated credential and they do.
[Certificates and Secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah24s.png)

[Federated Credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCtxU.png)

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ullnN.jpg)

Comment: After you created a new service connection for workload identity federation, did you update your pipeline to use the new service connection?

Comment: The error occurs if the client secret is expired, try creating the new client secret and pass and check if it resolves the issue.

Comment: You were right, just had to update my pipeline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just had to update my pipeline with the new Service Principal Name, then it worked.